# Sequelize query problem with where clause

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to convert this sql statement to sequelize:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN PartnerCustomerMapping p
ON c.customernumber = p.customer_number
WHERE c.customerNumber = '12345'


const customer = await loginDB.Customer.findOne({
  where: { customerNumber },
  include: [
    {
      model: loginDB.PartnerCustomerMapping,
      required: false,
      on: {
        customer_number: loginDB.Customer.customerNumber,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

but getting

Error: WHERE parameter "customer_number" has invalid "undefined" value

Comment: How do you fill customerNumber ? Can you also provide your model definition please?